# How does Google App Engine Instance hours counted in this particular situation?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I got an app built on top of App Engine.

We got a User class and many other classes as well. When user loged in.

How Google count the `Instance hours` when I do the following:

```
User user=request.getParameter("user");
```

I also have public static variable to hold chat messages & that could be called every 5 seconds if a user enter chat room (**note:** if many users enter the chat room then that variable could be called many times every 5 seconds), as the following:

```
public static Map<User, ConcurrentHashMap<User, CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>>> chatRoomConcurrentMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<User, ConcurrentHashMap<User, CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>>>();
```

If that is the case then how Google count the instance hours of that static variable?

SO, **How does Google count instance hour when we instantiate an object and when we call a public variable?**

Answer (score 1):

Instance hours calculations are done based on [app instance uptime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/scaling#instance_billing) and [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class), not on particular object instantiation or variable access inside the app's code.

If your app receives requests less than 15 minutes apart it will be billed (in terms of instance hours) at least as a constantly up instance (more if multiple instances are alive at the same time).